# Define ActiveRecord method to work with different ActiveRecord Relations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Let say that we have a method in a

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.stats
        # do something and returns a hash
    end
end
```

The method needs to iterate over the records and possibly call `each`.

I want to use this method with `scopes`, `where`, `all`, etc. Like following:

```
MyModel.all.stats
#=> one hash
MyModel.where("created_at > ?", 1.day.ago).stats
#=> another hash
MyModel.funny.stats
#=> funny hash
...
```

Is this possible? I need to pass the `ActiveRecord Relation` as a parameter or the scopes as parameters?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Rails 5.2.0 @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the scope inside the `stats` method will be the Relation

```
def self.stats
  count
end

MyModel.all.stats 
# => 10
MyModel.where("created_at > ?", 1.day.ago).stats
# => 5
```

Here is a good resource http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

If you want to iterate over the records, you could use the `find_each` method:

```
def self.stats
  find_each do |my_model|
    puts my_model.id
  end
end
```

Comment: I see, but how do I iterate over the relation? Can it be done?

Comment: yes, you can use any `ActiveRecord::Relation` method

Comment: @Rodrigo: not any, though. You can do `MyModel.all.map(...)`, but you can't put the `map` in `stats` (or, at least, it doesn't work on my machine). This magical method proxying is not the easiest thing to grasp.

Comment: @Rodrigo, when I try to use `each`, gives me the following error `undefined method \`each' for MyModel (call 'MyModel.connection' to establish a connection):Class`

Comment: use `find_each`. If you use `each` it won't work when you're in a unescoped